# How to change the variable for x axes in a plot?

Tags: plotting

I have a function depending r, for example
`f[r_]:=2*(1/a)Exp[-r/a]`
I want to plot  `a r^2 f[r]^2` vs `r/a`, How to do this? I tried this
`Plot[a *r^2 *f[r]^2, {r/a, 0, 8}, PlotRange -> All]` but it returns `$Failed`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Plot` isn't designed to handle arbitrary expressions as a domain.  Replace `r` with `a rdividedbya` where `rdividedbya` is a symbol name that the language can use.

```
Plot[a*r^2*f[r]^2/.r->a rdividedbya,{rdividedbya,0,8},PlotRange->All]
```

This replacement happens before the expression `a*r^2*f[r]` is evaluated and is effectively the same as

```
Plot[a*(a rdividedbya)^2*f[a rdividedbya]^2,{rdividedbya,0,8},PlotRange->All]
```

Replacement saved us the work of typing `a rdividedbya` twice.  We could even be so lazy as to solve the equation $\text{rdividedbya}=\frac ra$ for $r$ with Mathematica, but that's overkill in this situation.